# Decision Tree Using Python

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz, decision-tree

I am creating a decision tree using a dataset named as "wine": i am trying following code to execute:

```
dt = c.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Creating the image of the decision tree:

```
def show_tree(tree, features, path):
    f = io.StringIO()
    export_graphviz(tree, out_file=f, feature_names=features)
    pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(f.getvalue()).write_png(path)
    img = misc.imread(path)
    plt.rcParams["figure.figuresize"] = (20 , 20)
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Calling the image:

```
show_tree(dt, features, 'dec_tree_01.png')
```

but when i call the image it gives the following error:

```
GraphViz's executables not found
```

I have installed  graphviz-2.38msi from there website...but the same error is continuously showing.

I have also added environment variables string in the user variable like this:

```
 %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;
```

But it could also not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try appending the path to os variable in code like

```
import os     
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin'
```

Note: Do it at top of he code before excution of show_tree()

Comment: i have done pip install graphviz...but its also not working...i am very much confused with the path... i have installed python on E drive...the graphviz folder was in C and i have paste it in E drive where my python setup originally exist... This also can not solve my issue.